# My rokoko imported armature has more bones than my armature. How properly to rebuild bone list and retarget animation

Tags: animation, rigging

Hi i am trying to use rokoko software in which i imported some video for walking reference and than i get armature with walking animation. But the issue is when i import that armature with walking animation in my blender, usually it has more bones than my armature, and don't know how properly to rebuild bone list and retarget animation, and because of that when i try to implement rokoko imported animation my end result is not that smooth ,or sometimes is plainly wrong. Like my arms are mixed etc. Does some one know how to overcome this problem or any advice in general

Comment: Hello, you need to make sure that the bones have the same name, same orientation and so on